# If $V$ is irreducible then dim $Hom(V, W)^G$ is the multiplicity of $V$ in $W$?

Tags: representation-theory

From Fulton and Harris, p. 16,

> If $V$ is irreducible then dim $Hom(V, W)^G$ is the multiplicity of $V$ in $W$ by Schur's lemma.

The above is for a finite group $G$.

I tried to prove this but can't quite finish it.

For a map $\varphi \in Hom(V, W)^G$, we know that $Ker(V)$ is trivial, because V is irreducible.

Therefore from Schur's lemma $\varphi(V)$  is an isomorphism onto its image and $\varphi = \lambda I$.

So, we have now that each $\varphi$ maps a 1-dimensional irreducible rep, $V$ onto itself in $W$, and the dimension of $Hom(V, W)^G$ tells us how many different one dimensional subspaces of $W$ it maps into, or the multiplicity of $V$ in $W$.

Is my argument basically correct? Also, does this say anything about the dimension of W? I think not, since W may not just be a direct sum of representations of $V$.

Comment: You cannot assume $V$ is one-dimensional - in general, it won't be. Even if $V$ is one-dimensional, the multiplicity of $V$ in $W$ is not the same as the number of one-dimensional subspaces of $W$ (which is uncountably infinite). Do you have Maschke's theorem available? And the fact that $\hom$ distributes over direct sums?

Comment: Fulton and Harris haven't explicitly mentioned Maschke's theorem. I should have mentioned that they are restricting to $G$, where $G$ is a finite group. They do show that for finite groups that if $W$ is a subrep, then $V=W\oplus W'$ an that any representation for a finite group is a direct sum of irreducible reps. I am also not aware that hom distributes over direct sums. Your comment about $V$ not being one dimensional was illuminating. I will edit my argument in light of that.

Comment: It sounds like you have Maschke's theorem available to you in all but name. That homs distribute is, I would argue, an essential ingredient in really *understanding* this proposition.

Comment: I think I digested your suggestions and wrote up an answer, albeit a bit clumsily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the hints that runway44@'s suggested, I think the argument is roughly like so.

From a corollary of Schur's lemma, for finite groups a representation $V$ is decomposable into a direct sum of irreducible representations.

So we can take, $$W = V^1 \oplus ... V^i \oplus U^1\oplus ...U^j$$
where the $V^i$ are isomorphic representations of $V$ and the $U^j$ are any other representations.

Now, as mentioned in the comments above,
$$Hom(V,V^1 \oplus ... V^i \oplus U^1\oplus ...U^j) \cong Hom(V,V^1) \oplus 
...Hom(V,V^i) \oplus Hom(V,U^1) \oplus...\oplus Hom(V,U^j)$$

We get this via projection maps $\pi_V^i$ and $\pi_U^j$. This follows from the fact that  for $w \in W$, $w = v^1+...v^i+u^1+...u^j$, uniquely.

So, $\varphi_{V^i} = \pi_{V^i} \circ \varphi$.

Now if we restrict to $Hom(V,W)^G$, the subspace of $G$-linear maps,
$V$ is irreducible, therefore, $\varphi_{V^i}$ is an isomorphism onto its image or the trivial map.
And if it is an isomorphism, $\varphi_{V^i} = \lambda I$ from Schur's lemma.
And $\varphi_{U^i}$ are all the trivial rep.

Therefore, each map in $Hom(V,W)^G$, consists of choosing a $\lambda^i$ for each $V^i$ in the decomposition of $W$. Hence, the dimension of $Hom(V,W)^G$, is just the multiplicity of the $V^i$.

Comment: Yes. Also worth mentioning the hom-distributivity and projection maps are $G$-equivariant/intertwining.